# JavaScript/jQuery tool to read data from CSV file to use in API endpoint

Tags: javascript, api, jquery, csv

I am looking for a recommendation for a JavaScript library or jQuery plugin. I need to take a CSV file, read an id number from one of the columns, and plug that id number into an API GET request to get info regarding that id number. If it matters, I will be taking the info in the response and add it into the CSV file that I got the id number from.